# node.js connect to server socket, dont know how to authenticate with password

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, passwords, server

I am building a desktop audio streaming application, which will be a client, i wish to connect to a server socket to stream audio, i have the host ip, the port and password. I am using node to connect:

```
var client = net.connect(serverDetails, function() { //'connect' listener
  console.log('client created!');

});

client.on('connect', function() {
  console.log('connected to: '+serverDetails.host+' port: '+serverDetails.port );
  //client.write(serverDetails.password+'\r\n');

});

client.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('sending data to server!');
  console.log(data.toString());
});

client.on('end', function() {
  console.log('disconnected from server');
  client.end();
});
```

at the moment it connects and the disconnects straight away, how can i pass the password so that the connection remains open? after which i can stream/send data to this socket.

Comment: You're making a tcp connection, but you don't mention the protocol the server is using. Is it telnet, http(s), something homegrown? If it's an http(s) server, I would recommend the request module.

Comment: its an ICY protocol, so going off the documentation from [link](https://forums.radiotoolbox.com/viewtopic.php?t=74) suggests i write the password (which i have commented above), tried that however i still get disconnected straightaway. it would also help to receive a response from server, so if there is a way to output the response on `console.log` that would help to debug.